# How to animate(move) a UIButton, keeping it touchable during the move?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uibutton

It seems that when you animate a UIButton, the real button is always at the destination position.  Animation is just a "movie".
In this code, while in the animation, the button gets the event only if i touch the empty final destination (centered at 600x900). If I touch it as i see it in the showing position, meaning at some point where the button is being drawn (in the middle of the animation) it gets nothing.

```
CGPoint point;
point.x = 600;
point.y = 900;
[UIView animateWithDuration:16 
        delay:0 
        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent)
        animations:^{

            [movingbutton setCenter:point];
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            NSLog(@"animation completed");
        }
];
```

Cant figure out how to make the animating button touchable in the correct animation path. Any idea?
Thanx!

Comment: Sure it was. What are bounty points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use an NSTimer, and manually move it (change the frame) a few pixels each step.

Is ok for you?

Comment: Sounds quite resource guzzler, is it?

Comment: No but thank you anyway! (im not that lazy ;) Just wondering if were a sweeter solution. UIView animate... behavior is somehow disapointing.

Comment: Despite than elegance is where you find it, if it were up to me i would make it optonal. Cant imagine what would be the situation where a button acting as a button would be weird.